# Transmit Sound/Audio from One Cisco Phone to Another

Tags: rtp, telephony, cisco, cisco-jtapi

I need to transfer audio from one Cisco IP phone to another. Right now, I am streaming music using VLC media player through RTP to a Cisco IP phone (model CP-9971). On the phone, I send the following post request to start listening to the music from VLC.

```
<CiscoIPPhoneExecute><ExecuteItem URL="RTPRx:ipaddressA:port"/></CiscoIPPhoneExecute>
```

I am able to listen to the music from the ip phone after sending this xml. However, I am unable to send the music from this phone to another phone. I have used the following xml to transmit RTP stream to another phone.

```
<CiscoIPPhoneExecute><ExecuteItem URL="RTPTx:ipaddressB:port"/>  </CiscoIPPhoneExecute>
```

I have then used this XML to receive the RTP on the second phone.

```
<CiscoIPPhoneExecute><ExecuteItem URL="RTPRx:ipaddressB:port"/></CiscoIPPhoneExecute>
```

The music plays on the first phone and the music is not transmitted to the second phone. On the second phone, I can hear anything that is being transmitted from the mic of the first phone (like a regular call from first to second phone).

So my question is if there is way to transmit the audio from the headset of the first phone to the mic of the first phone so that the second phone can listen to the music. I don't even know if this is the right approach. I just need any kind of audio to be transmitted between these two phones during a call for sound quality reports. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the guide that I am using right now.
https://developer.cisco.com/fileMedia/download/0d2f0d08-c7a4-48b9-8bc2-0bf69ab27382

Answer (score 2):

What are you describing is not really possible, especially via the IP Phone Services XML interface.

I'm not entirely clear on your use-case, but the scenario is vaguely similar to what happens during a 'built-in-bridge' based recording or silent-monitoring call.  For those feature, with a call in progress, a recording/monitoring request is made (via JTAPI or TAPI) which causes the phone to create an 'invisible' additional call to the target destination number, copying the media stream.  It should be possible to build an an that uses a CTI port to call a target phone and play an audio file towards it, then issue a JTAPI silent-monitor request to the target phone to fork a call to a destination number - which would be a 2nd CTI port controlled by the app, which would answer and receive the forked media stream.

See the JTAPI Developer Guide for further information about CTI ports and silent monitoring.